# Will a VRRP fail over cause TCP connection closed and need to re-connect?

Tags: tcp

I'm connecting to remote server with persistent connection, and the network devices between me and remote server use VRRP to create a VIP and do fail-over when one device or link failed.

Will the fail-over cause TCP connection broken and I need to handle such a situation to re-connect remote server, or I can ignore this, just like vmware's VMotion?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the application keepalive, and VRRP advertisement interval setting. But most likely it should be OK to ignore it.

Failover is the most important feature of VRRP to make sure that hosts using the VIP get minimal impact when there is an outage (e.g. the Master VRRP router goes down). That said, there is still an impact, which is loss of connectivity via the VIP.

You can check the VRRP configuration to estimate the duration of that loss. If VRRP advertisement interval (i.e. keepalive interval) is configured to be 1second (which is the default value for both version 2 and 3), then it'll take 1second * 3 = 3 seconds for the backup node to detect the failure, plus some time for the backup to change its state to master. So in total between 3-4 seconds. if the advertisement interval is shorter than that, the time of the no connectivity will also be shorter, following the same formula described here.

So the question really is, what would happen during the time of no connectivity to outside the LAN? TCP 
inherently doesn't mind idle time of 3 seconds or any duration once the connection is established, so as long as the VRRP failover completes, TCP will not have noticed anything.

However, the application may implement its own keepalive to monitor the connection over TCP. And if that interval is shorter than VRRP advertisement interval, it may think there is a breakage of connection during the VRRP failover. But it should be rare that an application would set its keepalive to be as short as a few seconds. E.g., for SSH, it's usually set to 60 seconds.

In sum, it shouldn't be a problem. But if it is, check settings on both application keepalive and VRRP advertisement interval and adjust as needed. Note that you may not want the VRRP advertisement interval to be too short as it would generates more keepalives than necessary, which uses LAN bandwidth.